# Where should product information live when using Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

What is the right place to store things like product price, title, description when using Stripe, when many products are present?

The app I'm building will potentially have hundreds of products and I would like to easily be able to list them, paginate, search. Should this product data be duplicated both in my database and in Stripe?

The products in question are going to be courses, for an e-learning platform. They need to be integrated with the rest of my schema, so they do need to exist in my database too, but I would like to avoid duplication of certain fields, if possible. I wonder if there's a recommended approach for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me I would cache this information in my database and sync it in Stripe as needed.

You want the product and pricing information in Stripe since it's needed for their Product and Price APIs. It's used to display detailed information in email receipts or invoices, on hosted pages like Checkout and in various reconciliation options.

You also want the information in your database since you don't want to hit Stripe's API every time you need to retrieve a product's name or pricing details though especially if you have many products.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll go with this approach then.